# How did my predecessor use TextTemplating.14 to generate a type of partial class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, t4

The previous co-op has created an automatically generated html file that had data entered by the user. I am trying to duplicate this, but I am struggling to find a way to allow the .tt file to have the scope it needs to plug in the data.

The output of his .tt file looks like this... see below for his .tt file.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version: 14.0.0.0
//  
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace myNamespace
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to produce the template output
    /// </summary>

    #line 1 "C:/path to .tt file"
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating", "14.0.0.0")]
    public partial class Template : TemplateBase
    {
#line hidden
        /// <summary>
        /// Create the template output
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string TransformText()
        {
            this.Write("<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<title>Telematics Configuration Job - ");

            #line 8 "C:/file path to .tt file"
            this.Write(this.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Job.JobNumber));

            #line default
            #line hidden
            this.Write(@"</title>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""JobDatasheetStyles.css"">
</head>
<body>
<div id=""Page"">
    <div id=""Document_Header"">
        <h1 class=""Document_Header_Item"" id=""asdf"">
            <span class=""Header_Text"" id=""asdf_Header_Text"">asdf Industries Inc.</span>
        </h1>
        <div class=""Document_Header_Item"" id=""Datasheet_Name"">
            <span class=""Header_Text"" id=""Datasheet_Name_Text"">Telematics Configuration Job Datasheet</span>
        </div>
        <div class=""Document_Header_Item"" id=""asdfdd"">
            <span class=""Header_Text_Sub"" id=""asdfas"">Manufactured with asdfversion ");
```

Incomplete, but it just finishes the html file. See below for the .tt file.

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Telematics Configuration Job - <#= Job.JobNumber #></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JobDatasheetStyles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Page">
    <div id="Document_Header">
        <h1 class="Document_Header_Item" id="asdf">
            <span class="Header_Text" id="asdf">asdf Industries Inc.</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="Document_Header_Item" id="Datasheet_Name">
            <span class="Header_Text" id="Datasheet_Name_Text">Telematics Configuration Job Datasheet</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Document_Header_Item" id="asdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the tutorials online I found failed to mention that I was to use RunTime TextTemplate, instead of TextTemplate.